# remove a line with special character with given pattern

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sed, awk

I'm trying to get the lines with special characters which is not prefixed with `\`. Below are the special characters:

```
^$%.*+?!(){}[]|\
```

I need to check all the above special characters which is not prefixed with `\` in 2nd column. I'm trying with awk to complete this, but no luck. I want the output as below.

input.txt

```
1,ap^ple
2,o$range
3,bu+tter
4,gr(ape
5,sm\(ok\e
6,ra\in
7,p+la\\y
8,wor\+k
```

output.txt

```
1,ap^ple
2,o$range
3,bu+tter
4,gr(ape
5,sm\(ok\e
6,ra\in
7,p+la\\y
```

7th row and 5 row are in output.txt because there  is 2 special charcters(one is with backslash another without backslash)

Comment: Should a line containing "\\\" be output or not? Why?

Answer (score 2):

"final" final edit: I wanted to allow "\x" whatever x is, but the OP seems to not want that, so I fixed it too.

After trying to find a "clever" regexp (which choked on "\\" or any impair number of "\", but apparently worked for the rest...)

I re-wrote it in awk to do it in a "state automata" way:

The idea:

If in "normal mode", we encounter a special char other than "\" ? : we print the line!
 If in "normal mode", we encounter a "\" ? : we enter "escaped mode", and in that mode, ignore the next char
      (but if we don't have a next char, we need to print that line too!)

the script:

```
awk -F"," '
  {
    IN_ESCAPED_MODE=0 ;
    for (i=1 ; i<=length($2) ; i++)
     {  char=substr($2,i,1)

        if ( IN_ESCAPED_MODE == 0)
     {  if ( index(".^$%*+?!(){}[]|",char) > 0 )
             {  print $0 ; break ;
             }

            if ( index("\\" , char ) > 0 )
             {  IN_ESCAPED_MODE=1 ; continue ;
             }
         }

        if ( IN_ESCAPED_MODE == 1)
     {   if ( index(".^$%*+?!(){}[]|\\",char) > 0 )
           {  IN_ESCAPED_MODE=0 ; continue ;
               }
             else
               {  IN_ESCAPED_MODE=0 ; print $0; break;
               }
         }
     }

    if (IN_ESCAPED_MODE == 1)
     {
        print $0 ; break ;
     }

  }
'  input.txt > output.txt
```

With this change, you will have the same output as the OP, which prints a line when it contains "\e" for example... Which I find weird: to me "\e" is fine, we can "escape" anything?

With that input:

```
1,ap^ple
2,o$range
3,bu+tter
4,gr(ape
5,sm\(ok\e
6,ra\in
7,p+la\\y
8,wor\+k

10,\
11,\\
12,\\\
13,.
14,\.
15,..
16,^
17,\^
18,$
19,\$
20,%
21,\%
22,*
23,\*
24,+
25,\+
26,?
27,\?
28,!
29,\!
30,(
31,\(
32,)
33,\)
34,{
35,\{
36,}
37,\}
38,[
39,\[
40,]
41,\]
42,|
43,\|
```

it outputs:

```
1,ap^ple
2,o$range
3,bu+tter
4,gr(ape
5,sm\(ok\e
6,ra\in
7,p+la\\y
10,\
12,\\\
13,.
15,..
16,^
18,$
20,%
22,*
24,+
26,?
28,!
30,(
32,)
34,{
36,}
38,[
40,]
42,|
```

(so it appears to really work this time !)

If you prefer to allow **any** "\x" and NOT only if "x" is a SPECIAL char:

change the "middle lines":

```
        if ( IN_ESCAPED_MODE == 1)
         {  if ( index(".^$%*+?!(){}[]|\\",char) > 0 )
             {  IN_ESCAPED_MODE=0 ; continue ;
             }
            else
             {  IN_ESCAPED_MODE=0 ; print $0; break;
             }
         }
```

into:

```
        if ( IN_ESCAPED_MODE == 1)
         {  IN_ESCAPED_MODE=0 ; continue ;
         }
```

for historical reason : the regexp (which worked in "most" cases but choked in some, for example if there was "\\") :

```
 egrep '[^\][].^$%*+?!(){}[|]|[^\][\][^].^$%*+?!(){}[|\]'   input.txt > output.txt
```

But that one will not display the line 12, for example...

A good read: http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html  .... and http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Gory-Details.html  (scary ...)

Comment: the sed output is same as input.txt

Comment: Still no difference, i could see the line `8,wor\+k` in the output.txt

Comment: ah, true, I didn't take into account : "\" followed by a special char! (therefore, my version sees "\" and thinks it's a "\" without a proper "\" before it... so it prints the line out). Thx, good catch. I'll try to fix it.

Comment: fixed. I hope... (there may be special cases, probably aroudn a weird number of "\")

Comment: hmm, case "d" is wrong... Interresting. I need to figure out how to have "]" inside a "[]" to fix it

Comment: I fixed it again.. but there is still weird cases: "\\\" !! tough one, using that method only. I probably need to use another method: look for "\" and see it what follows IS a special char (and "consume it" before matching the rest of the line)... Output if not. And if you encounter another special char (except "\"), then it's wrong and you output it too.

Comment: @GanzRicanz: final edit : I think I got it this time ^^ using state automata instead of trying to find a clever regexp (which easily choke on complex cases).

Comment: thanks a ton for your effort, can you please explain about sed command. sorry if it's too basic.

Comment: Also im not able to execute the awk command .. it;s version specific?

Comment: @GanzRicanz: hello. Did this work for you since the other day? (for the awk: just copy the whole script (from `awk ....` until `... input.txt > output.txt`) and paste it in the command line. You need to be in the directory containing input.txt. Then look at the file 'output.txt'. If it doesn't work, can you give me error messages?  [awk can differ from system to system]

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
awk '
{
    line=$0
    sub(/\\[\^$%.*+?!(){}\[\]|\\]/,"")
    if(/[\^$%.*+?!(){}\[\]|\\]/)
        print line
}' input.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed '/[]\\^$%.*+?!(){}[|]/ {
  h
  s/\\[]\\^$%.*+?!(){}[|]/_/g
  /[]\\^$%.*+?!(){}[|]/ {
    x
    p
    }
  }' YourFile
```

Depending of shell and sed could be interpreted (especialy the `\`) differently. Works on my AIX/KSH